# Handler thread instance becomes null after creation of the thread

Tags: android-handlerthread

I am getting null pointer exception while quit the thread using its handler thread instance, The instance value becomes null after its creation. If i make the variable as static then I didn't face this problem. Can any one explain me about why the Handler thread instance becomes null after its creation, Below code will explain briefly about my problem.

```
private class MyHandler extends Handler{

    private HandlerThread hThread;

    private MyHandler(Looper looper){
         super(looper);
    }

    public MyHandler(){

       //Created my handler thread instance here
       hThread = new HandlerThread(... , Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
       hThrad.start();

       new MyHandler(hThread.getLooper);
    }
```

Here is my handle message method:

```
  public void HandlerMessage(Message msg){
        super(msg);
     try{


       /*Here I am executing some utility methods*/
     }catch(Exception exce){

     }finally{

         /*While reading the instance of Handler thread it says null*/
            hThread.quit();//Throws null pointer exception.

     }

    }
}
```